# React Native ios Simulator - Simulator is installed but is identified as '; don't know what that is

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, react-native

I'm trying to launch the ios simulator to try an React Native App. I did't hace XCode installed until now.

To install my simulator, I had installed XCode, and I started a project "Simulator", to push "next" I needed a company name, I put "simu", after that, I clicked on "Project > Run", and I could see my simulator run.

In my CLI, when I launch the command yarnpkg run ios, I get this error:

```
Simulator is installed but is identified as 'simu.Simulator'; don't know what that is.
23:55:17: Failed to start simulator:

Unable to verify Xcode and Simulator installation.
```

I removed all my simulators, but the name persists, I had search how to change the identificator, but I dont find results.

I would like to know if I can change the "simu.Simulator" to Simulator, someone can help me?

Answer (score 17):

The issue you might be facing is there might not be command line tools selected in your xCode Preferences. In Preferences -> Location, Choose command line tool

[image]

Answer (score 6):

By default, after installing **Xcode** command-line not selected, so open Xcode and go to **Preferences >> Locations** and set **Command Line Tools**...

This worked for me in MAC High Sierra, **Xcode Version 9.3**:

[image: Xcode]

Press `i` to open iOS emulator...

[image: Press a to open Android device or emulator, or i to open iOS emulator.]

And You can see a cool new iPhone simulator like below image:

[image: React Native prints, I'm Alireza Dezfoolian, a Front End Developer!]

Answer (score 0):

For Expo 32, the other solutions didn't work for me.

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55302909/1417223) solved it for me: Just open the Simulator before invoking it from Expo.

Answer (score 0):

If the answer provided https://stackoverflow.com/a/45537180/11547611, does not work and you already have command line tools selected in XCode, try this command in the terminal,
npx expo start --ios
Basically, in my case I did not have Expo Go on the ios simulator, so it downloaded that, and ran my app.